# How can opening the developer tools of a browser stop server looping?

Tags: wordpress, oauth, developer-tools

I am having trouble loading a WordPress site page arrived at from an OAuth provider which seems to be causing an infinite loop on the server. But when I open up the developer tools of any browser (Chrome & Firefox so far), the looping stops and the page loads. It also doesn't loop if the dev tools are already opened. What could be changing that causes this looping to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev tools have a "Disable cache" checkbox on the Network tab, so it's possible that when they're open you're avoiding cache. Redirects are usually long-cached unless there's an explicit Cache-Control header.

To find out if it's a cache issue, you can try logging in on a private session, which doesn't shares cached assets with your regular session.

Comment: This happens with a private session.

Comment: Though this was also happening in a private session, like you said, it turned out to be a problem with cached headers being sent in redirects. This was fixed by explicitly making the headers not have a default expiration. Since this is a WordPress site, this was done by removing the "ExpiresDefault" value in the `.htaccess` file. Also, there was an issue with having mixed http/https redirects which was solved by forcing https at all times in `wp-config.php`.